# Combo Box Adding Items From An Existing Array

Tags: vb.net

So I have displayed my parallel array into the combo box when the form loads. The User clicks on a name and the phone number is then displayed. So everything there works fine. My next goal is to prompt the user for a new contact, they enter a new name into one textbox, then a new number into the other textbox. The contact name is then displayed onto the combo box. When I click on the name it gives me number on the first try, But  then  I enter a new contact, and the information from the first contact is still being displayed everytime I enter a new contact . I don't know why, any ideas?

```
Module
Option Explicit On
Module MainModule
Public strPeople() As String = {"Kyle", "John", "Jake", "Donna", "Carly","Ty", "Mavis"}
Public strPhoneNumbers() As String = {"945-1232", "804-2329", "290-7321", "928-4569", "205-9893", "320-0195", "305-4520"}
Public count As Integer = 0
Public numCount As Integer = 0
End Module

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(strPeople)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim strPhoneNums As String = strPhoneNumbers(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)

    Label3.Text = "Phone Number: " & strPhoneNums

End Sub
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    If TextBox1.Text = "" And TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Name and Number")
    ElseIf TextBox1.Text <> "" And TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Number")
    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "" And TextBox2.Text <> "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Name")
    Else
        For Each Item As String In TextBox1.Text
            count += 1
            ReDim Preserve strPeople(6 + count)
            strPeople(count) = TextBox1.Text
        Next
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(strPeople(count))
        TextBox1.Clear()

        For Each Itm As String In TextBox2.Text
            numCount += 1
            ReDim Preserve strPhoneNumbers(6 + numCount)
            strPhoneNumbers(6 + numCount) = TextBox2.Text
        Next
        TextBox2.Clear()

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Learn to use List<T> collections instead of arrays.

Comment: My homework requires me to use arrays for this section. We are working on parallel arrays and being able to resize them

Comment: Is the problem with the Add click or after the Add click when selecting a contact from the combo box?

Comment: Yes that is the one!

Comment: It was an "or" question.  I'm guessing you are looking for `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1` after you clear the TextBox2 line.  Just because you add an item to a ComboBox doesn't mean it's automatically selected.

Comment: After The Add click sorry

Comment: I used that line, but i'm still getting the same number as my first contact. I just select the name automatically, my problem is the information being a duplicate

Comment: Remove your for each loops.  You aren't adding multiple things at once, you are only adding one thing at a time.

Comment: It Worked!!! I can't believe it!. I owe you big time thank thank you!